# SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol when trying to access HTTPS URL

Tags: apache2, ssl, openssl, wordpress

While trying to create a staging environment for my **WORDPRESS** website, I am not quite able to setup the HTTPS configuration.

I copied the wordpress folder and backed up Mysql database and was able to have a copy of my website, but whenever I click on any link, it will take me to HTTPS url and shows me a `SSL connection error`.

### Environment

- Vagrant VM Ubuntu server `Precise64`
- Chef to configure my host
- Apache2 w/ SSL mod
- Wordpress

### UNAME

```
uname -a
Linux test-www 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:13:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### SSL Configuration

```
vagrant@test-www:/etc/apache2$ more ssl.conf 
<VirtualHost 192.168.33.10:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName test-www.domain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_secure.log
        LogLevel info

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/wildcard.domain.com/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/wildcard.domain.com/server.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/wildcard.domain.com/test-www.domain.com.ca.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

### OPENSSL

```
vagrant@test-www:/etc/apache2$ openssl s_client -connect 192.168.33.10:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139816269579936:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:757:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 213 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

### WGET HTTP:443

```
vagrant@test-www:/etc/apache2$ wget http://192.168.33.10:443
--2015-02-02 17:24:31--  http://192.168.33.10:443/
Connecting to 192.168.33.10:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-02-02 17:24:31 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

### WGET HTTPS

```
vagrant@test-www:/etc/apache2$ wget https://192.168.33.10
--2015-02-02 17:25:23--  https://192.168.33.10/
Connecting to 192.168.33.10:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
vagrant@test-www:/etc/apache2$
```

## APACHE2.CONF

```
#
# Generated by Chef
#
# Based on the Ubuntu apache2.conf

ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
LockFile /var/lock/apache2/accept.lock

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
#
PidFile /var/run/apache2.pid

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
##

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          1
    MinSpareServers       1
    MaxSpareServers       2
    ServerLimit           5
    MaxClients            3
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          1
    ServerLimit           3
    MaxClients            3
    MinSpareThreads       10
    MaxSpareThreads       20
    ThreadsPerChild       64
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

User www-data
Group www-data

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

#
# DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain


#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

# COOK-1021: Dummy LoadModule directive to aid module installations
#LoadModule dummy_module modules/mod_dummy.so

# Include module configuration:
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf


# Include ports listing
Include /etc/apache2/ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
#

# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# Putting this all together, we can internationalize error responses.
#
# We use Alias to redirect any /error/HTTP_<error>.html.var response to
# our collection of by-error message multi-language collections.  We use
# includes to substitute the appropriate text.
#
# You can modify the messages' appearance without changing any of the
# default HTTP_<error>.html.var files by adding the line:
#
#   Alias /error/include/ "/your/include/path/"
#
# which allows you to create your own set of files by starting with the
# /usr/share/apache2/error/include/ files and copying them to /your/include/path/,
# even on a per-VirtualHost basis.  The default include files will display
# your Apache version number and your ServerAdmin email address regardless
# of the setting of ServerSignature.
#
# The internationalized error documents require mod_alias, mod_include
# and mod_negotiation.  To activate them, uncomment the following 30 lines.

#    Alias /error/ "/usr/share/apache2/error/"
#
#    <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/error">
#        AllowOverride None
#        Options IncludesNoExec
#        AddOutputFilter Includes html
#        AddHandler type-map var
#        Order allow,deny
#        Allow from all
#        LanguagePriority en cs de es fr it nl sv pt-br ro
#        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
#    </Directory>
#
#    ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 413 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 415 /error/HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 500 /error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 501 /error/HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 502 /error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 503 /error/HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 506 /error/HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES.html.var



# Include generic snippets of statements
Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

## PORTS.CONF

```
$ more ports.conf 
# This file was generated by Chef for my-vm-precise64.
# Do NOT modify this file by hand!

Listen *:80
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

then I also tried adding these into the `ports.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

## mods ssl.conf

```
vagrant@test-www:/etc/apache2$ grep "SSLv" -r *

mods-available/ssl.conf:#SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
mods-available/ssl.conf:# enable only secure protocols: SSLv3 and TLSv1, but not SSLv2
mods-available/ssl.conf:SSLProtocol all -SSLv2   <=== ?
mods-enabled/ssl.conf:#SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
mods-enabled/ssl.conf:# enable only secure protocols: SSLv3 and TLSv1, but not SSLv2
mods-enabled/ssl.conf:SSLProtocol all -SSLv2    <=== ?
```

Comment: Somewhere along the line, you're trying to negotiate in SSLv2/SSLv3, based on those errors. In most cases, SSLv3 is now *dead* and you should be instead using TLSv1/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2.  This is because SSLv2 is now LONG dead, and SSLv3 is dead recently due to the POODLE vulnerability. Provide us a copy of the Apache2 site configurations.

Comment: ERROR 404: Not Found. => looks like you are not doing ssl at all. did you try a wireshark to see what is actualy flowing ?

Comment: and is there something within /var/log/apache2/error_secure.log ? or /var/log/apache2/access.log /var/log/apache2/error.log ?

Comment: @ThomasW. I added the `apache2.conf` produced by my Chef config. I will also add `port.conf`

Comment: @ThomasW. how do I configure Apache2 to use `TLSv1/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2` instead?

Comment: @philippelhardy if I try to access `https://192.168.33.10/wp-admin/update-core.php`, I am getting `[Tue Feb 03 14:16:47 2015] [error] [client 192.168.33.1] Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01` and `access.log` doesn't show anything (??). I will update my question with these details.

Comment: @ThomasW. I have run a `grep "SSLv" -r *` from `/var/apache2` and found out that `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2`, could that be the problem?

Comment: issue resolved, my `ssl.conf` was in the wrong location. It should have been in `sites-enabled` folder. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, I had `ssl.conf` in `/etc/apache2` instead of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

after moving the file and restarting apache2 `service apache2 restart` it all worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had not enabled the site 'default-ssl'. Only '000-default' was listed in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` folder.

Enable SSL site on Ubuntu 14 LTS, Apache 2.4.7:

```
a2ensite default-ssl
service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Had exactly this problem after upgrading Ubuntu versions.

Comment: SSL enabled and working before upgrade, failure after upgrade.  Firefox said: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG;  wget said SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO.